# Override a single value defined a third-party configmap

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a very specific question.
I'm migrating Spring Boot to 2.7, and how the profiles are set changes a bit.
I have a `configmap` that my app uses, but the `configmap` is maintained by another team.

I have in my sts template:

```
      volumes:
      - name: third-party-cm
        configMap:
          name: third-party-cm-spring
```

That cm has the structure:

```
k get cm third-party-cm-spring -oyaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  application.yaml: |
    # Cluster Independent settings

    ---
    spring.profiles: env1
    third-party-stuff:
      stuff1:
        key1: value
        key2:
          value: blabla
........
```

I don't have access to the code that creates this `cm`, but I need to mount all that stuff as:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  application.yaml: |
    # Cluster Independent settings

    ---
    spring.config.activate.on-profile: env1
    third-party-stuff:
      stuff1:
        key1: value
        key2:
          value: blabla
........
```

So the `spring.profiles:` changes to `spring.config.activate.on-profile:` and the rest is what the original cm `third-party-cm-spring` has.
How do I achieve this in my Helm `sts` template without touching in any way the original `third-party-cm-spring` `configmap`? I have not found any solution...
Thank you!

Comment: I'd guess your only path forward is an `initContainer:` and `emptyDir: {}` to mount the vendor's CM into /random-path and mount the emptyDir in the place they are expecting the application.yaml; helm [does have a way of reading resources from the cluster](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function), but it only works during `install` and `upgrade`, not `template` which can be problematic depending on your needs, and (of course) would go poorly during first-install

Comment: Is `third-party-cm-spring` applied to the cluster and do you want to patch a key in the configmap when you want to install helm?

Comment: @Andromeda No, I cannot mutate the cm itself. I want to use it, but I need to use the overriden value in my app.

Comment: @mdaniel That makes total sense. I really appreciate your answer.